# Read from Value-Typed Function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been looking in ithe internet but couldnt find a solution. So i decide to ask here:

I've a table contains specifications of my products. It has colum names as: productCode, specName, specStr, visibility

I need to put all specs in a single string. Something like (for productcode=54S4): "Category: Electronics, Weight: 50g, Brand: XYZ"

I've to do this using sql server functions. So i created a value-typed function. i got specs of a single product in format of a table. Here is the function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getDescription1 (@code varchar(32))
RETURNS table
AS
RETURN (
SELECT (specName+': '+specStr+', ')as description
FROM productSpecs 
where specStr<>'' and visibility=1 and productCode=@code
)
```

As a result, I have a table. But i couldnt read the data in it using while or something.

Is my route true? If yes what to do now? If no enlighten me please...

Comment: Presumably, you are using SQL Server, so I fixed the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE FUNCTION getDescription1 (@code varchar(32))
RETURNS  nvarchar(1000)
AS
  DECLARE @p_str NVARCHAR(1000)
    SET @p_str = ''      
 SELECT @p_str = @p_str +  (specName+': '+specStr+', ')
     FROM productSpecs 
where specStr<>'' and visibility=1 and productCode=@code
 RETURN LEFT(@p_str, len(@p_str) -1)
```

Comment: Although data in my db are in Turkish char format, with this function, Turkish chars are converted to Latin. How to handle this problem? I need the result with Turkish collation...

Comment: what about Turkish char problem, can u help me on that too, please?

Comment: declare @p_str Nvarchar(1000) not varchar